# Discord.py "Как сделать что бы бот проверял сообщения в другом текстовом канале"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Как сделать что бы проверяло только в другом текстовом канале

```
@client.command
async def on_message( message ):
    await client.process_commands( message )
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in word:
        await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй такой код:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands( message )
    if message.channel.id == id нужного тебе канала:
        msg = message.content.lower()

        for i in список запрещенных слов:
            if i in msg:
                bot_send = ', извини, но здесь нельзя так разговаривать' 
                await message.channel.send("{} {}".format(message.author.mention, bot_send))
        del i
```